# MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8

My file is already encoded with UTF-8 in notepad++, why I am still getting this error?

by the way, I'm using jasperreports. .jrxml

```
    Oct 30, 2017 12:35:07 AM frmStart jButton_repActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:249)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:228)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:216)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:170)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:154)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:85)
    at frmStart.jButton_repActionPerformed(frmStart.java:556)
```

Comment: Is it stored as _UTF-8 without BOM_?

Comment: how to check if it is?

Comment: I saw in the notepad++

Encoding > 

I can't see UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/h3iz3j

Comment: is my notepad++ outdated? I can't see the option.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Fv47d

Comment: Interesting, your NP++ seems to have the opposite options, maybe mine is outdated, not sure. Seems to be okay though. Not sure what else it could be

Answer (score 0):

I believe the situation is that Xerces will accept UTF-8 input with a BOM if given a (binary) InputStream to read from, but if you give it a (character-based) reader as input, it will ask the Java I/O library to do the decoding, and that will fail.

So it depends how Jasper Reports is invoking Xerces. I don't know if you have any control over that.